# Very elementary question regarding integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to solve
$$\int \int^a_0f(x,a)dx da$$

Say we do not have a closed-form solution for $\int^a_0f(x,a)dx$, but we do have a closed-form solution for $\int f(x,a) da$. Is there anyway we can simplify the double integration, by somehow utilizing the solution of $\int f(x,a) da$?

I don't think we can utilize the solution for $\int f(x,a) da$, since the range of the inner integral is dependent on the variable $a$. So I am pretty sure the answer to my question is 'no', but I am just checking my sanity here, with a slight hope someone tells me a magical trick to solve this.

Comment: What's the context of the question?

Comment: Think about the *region* being described by that integral.  If you fix $a$ first, then $x$ is between $0$ and $a$.  What happens if you fix $x$ first?  Where can $a$ lie?  You might try drawing a picture.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I am trying to compute a kernel for Gaussian process.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Hmm in my head I am picturing a 2D surface (over $x,a$ plane) created by $f(x,a)$. And the double integral indicates that I need to get the volume under the surface over the half-space where $a>x$. If this picture is correct, then I can reduce the double integral to a single integral, assuming I can obtain a close-form solution for the indefinite integral of $f(x,a)$ across $a$. Is this correct?

Comment: You shouldn't be imagining something in 3D.  *Draw a picture* of the $ax$-plane, and look at the region you are integrating over.  Of course, I am also assuming that your function $f$ is well-enough behaved that Fubini-Tonelli permits iterated integration...

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you. So I just drew a picture of the plane and I think I got it. If, for example, I want to compute $\int^b_0 \int^a_0f(x,a)dx da$, I am integrating over the region where $x<a<b, 0<x$, so it should be equivalent to $\int^b_0 \int^b_xf(x,a)da dx$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be 'yes'. Thanks, @XanderHenderson, for the direction.

$$\int^b_0 \int^y_0 f(x,y) dxdy =\int^b_0 \int^b_x f(x,y) dydx$$